# Why does spark-submit fail with "Missing application resource" with --jars option specified?

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to Spark and I am trying to add a local jar to spark submit by using --jars. My command is `./spark-submit --jars /home/parallels/Downloads/my_jar_name`

However, it seems not working with the feedback like this. I am wondering the cause of it and how to fix it.
[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots. Copy and paste the exception and [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) using code blocks: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1):

`--jars` simply adds jars to include on the driver and executor classpaths.

> **--jars JARS** Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver and executor classpaths.

`spark-submit` requires the path to the application jar (aka *app jar*) that you have **not** specified and hence the error.

```
./spark-submit --jars /home/parallels/Downloads/my_jar_name path_to_application.jar
```